# Angular MFE - WebPack5 - Module Federation - I18N translations

Tags: angular, webpack, i18next, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

We are working with multiple angular MFE projects (with nx), after successfully loading the host and remote modules and showing the page (through routes), the next step was translations.

I have a shared translations module that is loading `angular-i18next`
[image]

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { I18NextModule } from 'angular-i18next';
import { I18N_PROVIDERS } from './i18next.config';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, I18NextModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [I18N_PROVIDERS],
})
export class UtilTranslationsModule {

  // I setup the module providers for the root application.
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<UtilTranslationsModule> {

    return ({
      ngModule: UtilTranslationsModule,
      providers: [I18N_PROVIDERS],
    });

  }
```

with the i18Next options:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

import { defaultInterpolationFormat, I18NextModule, I18NEXT_SERVICE, ITranslationService } from 'angular-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import HttpApi from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { Languages } from './languages.constant';

/*
 * Platform and Environment providers/directives/pipes
 */
const i18nextOptions = {
  whitelist: Object.values(Languages),
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  debug: false, // true, // set debug?
  returnEmptyString: false,
  ns: ['common', 'error', 'auth'],
  defaultNS: 'common',
  interpolation: {
    format: I18NextModule.interpolationFormat(defaultInterpolationFormat),
  },
  // backend plugin options
  backend: {
    loadPath: 'locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    addPath: 'locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}',
    crossDomain: true,
  },
  // lang detection plugin options
  detection: {
    // order and from where user language should be detected
    order: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],

    // keys or params to lookup language from
    lookupCookie: 'lang',

    // cache user language on
    caches: ['localStorage', 'cookie'],

    // optional expire and domain for set cookie
    cookieMinutes: 10080, // 7 days
    cookieDomain: 'I18NEXT_LANG_COOKIE_DOMAIN',
  },
};
```

the module is shared in webpack `sharedMappings.register(tsConfigPath, ['@tgc/translations'], workspaceRootPath);`

and the files are loaded through the `i18next-http-backend` library.
The host loads the translations correctly but the `remote` module isnt showing any translations `( 'auth:login.title' | i18nextCap)`

I have found some similar issues but it only contains the assets issue, like [angular mfe assets issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69192229/angular-mfe-webpack5-module-federation-image-path-issue). The translation files are also exported as assets in the `project.json`

hope the issue is clear, if not I always can add a example code here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that i had to make a certain file shareable:

`'angular-i18next': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },`

[image]

Comment: How did you end up sharing your i18n files with the shell?

Comment: @eddy at this moment I have a shared (translation) Module that my shell imports and also on my MFE module